# __key__ parameter for classes in Python

Tags: python, sorting, key

I have an array of vectors and I want to sort them by length:

```
class Vector:

     def __init__(self, x, y):
       self.x, self.y = x, y

     def __add__(a, b):
       return Vector(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y)

     def __str__(a):
       return str(a.x) + ' ' + str(a.y) + '\n'

     def __key__(self):
       return self.x * self.x + self.y * self.y


a = []
a.append(Vector(1,2))
a.append(Vector(1, 1))
a.sort()
print("".join(map(str,a)))
```

It says: "unorderable types: Vector() < Vector()"
It wants me to create `lt`, `gt`.. methods. But I want to sort without using `cmp`. Is it possible?

Comment: Note that you probably shouldn't use `__key__` as the name of one of your methods.  method names bracketed by pairs of underscores are reserved for special means by the specification (This means that at any time, Guido could decide he wants to add `__key__` as part of the python data model and your method could cause some pretty interesting (undesired) behavior.)

Comment: Also, if you're just looking for a nice vector class, you might want to look into `numpy`.  It provides "ndarray"s which behave very similar to vectors, support a very interesting (and useful) form of indexing, and do all of the mathematical operations in C which makes them a good bit faster than you'd get with rolling your own implementation.

Comment: @mgilson it appears that OP was expecting `__key__` to already be defined as part of the Python data model, with behaviour analogous to the `key` keyword parameter to `list.sort`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel -- You might be right (I had considered the possibility), but I was hoping that phrasing my comment as I did would make it obvious that was not the case.

Comment: Minor suggestion: `__str__` shouldn't return a newline `\n`, let that be handled by `print`, `join`, etc. statements/functions.

Comment: Also, it is customary to name the first argument to methods `self` rather than `a` (unless it is a `@staticmethod` or something).  It isn't required, but when I read your code, it forced me to do a double take because that convention is very firmly engrained in my psyche.

Answer (score 8):

I would implement `__lt__` and `__eq__` and then use the [`functools.total_ordering`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) class decorator to get the rest of the comparison methods.

If it doesn't make sense to have your vectors ordered like that, then you can always just use the `key` keyword to `sort` (or `sorted` for that matter):

```
mylist.sort(key = lambda v: v.x**2 + v.y**2)
```

Comment: This is neat, but semantically a bit iffy: vectors aren't really totally ordered by length since for example (0,1) and (1,0) are different but would compare equal.

Comment: @katrielalex -- Somewhat True.  You're free to implement `__eq__` and `__lt__` however you see fit.  You could make `__eq__` defined as `self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y` for example.  In this particular case, I don't really see how one vector can be "less than" another, so in this case, I'd probably default to using a `key` is sorting, but I thought that I would include `functools.total_ordering` as it more closely resembles what it looks like OP is trying to do.  (It's also a useful decorator to know regardless).

Comment: I think this is a cool idea, and I think it should work based on the [`source`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/functools.py#l53). The question is: does `total_ordering` define `__gt__` in a way that returns `False` when `x` and `y` are equal? And it appears to from the source. The result in this case will be not a total order, but a [total preorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering#Total_preorders); what is total here is really the _relation_, rather than the order.

Comment: Though looking back at this, the problem that `__eq__` will return true for two different vectors remains. That's probably not ideal...

Comment: total_ordering has subtle pitfalls: https://regebro.wordpress.com/2010/12/13/python-implementing-rich-comparison-the-correct-way/

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D -- This is true I suppose.  The pitfalls happen when you are trying to compare objects of different types.  In *most* cases, you probably shouldn't be doing this anyway...

Answer (score 6):

You have two variants here: implement `__cmp__` function in `Vector` class or perform sorting this way:

```
...
a.sort(key=Vector.__key__)
```

Comment: I'd suggest renaming the `__key__` method to `__len__`, since the returned value is in fact the length of the vector. Then use `a.sort(key=len)`, which shows intent much more clearly.

Comment: @lazyr certainly not! `__len__` is for the length *of sequences*; Python expects it to return an integer. (Also, the value currently being returned is the square of the length.)

Comment: @lazyr - I agree with the principle that `__key__` isn't the best name (even aside from it possibly meaning something specific in the future, it isn't very specific), but `__len__` is a little questionable, since `help(len)` says it is "the number of items of a sequence or mapping". I would probably define it as a separate function (not a method) called something like `norm`.

Comment: Also, it is worth pointing out that `__cmp__` goes away in python 3.x.  (which the OP *might* be using)

Answer (score 2):

[Python docs says](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) that lt/le/gt/ge/eq/ne are

> [...] the so-called “rich comparison” methods, and are called for
>   comparison operators in preference to __cmp__()

If you implement a [`__cmp__(self, other)`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__) method, it should be used for comparison/sort operations.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that `__cmp__` is no longer used in python 3.x

Comment: @mgilson indeed, and given the `print` usage, OP may already be using Py3.

Comment: @Ivc -- Yeah, and "old-style" syntax for class declaration (although that could just be because the OP doesn't know to always inherit from `object` in python 2.x).