# Python: Create __hash__ and comparison functions compactly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As pointed out in [__key__ parameter for classes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158351/key-parameter-for-classes-in-python), Python3.x has `functools.total_ordering`, but it still requires manually implementing `__lt__`, `__hash__` and `__eq__` manually.

In many cases what I need thus boils down to the still repetitive pattern

```
@functools.total_ordering
class X:
    ...
    _key = lambda self: (self.field1, self.field2)
    __lt__ = lambda self, other: self._key() < other._key()
    __eq__ = lambda self, other: self._key == other._key
    __hash__ = lambda self: hash(self._key())
```

The motivation for the `_key` function is the `key` parameter used in utility funcitons like `sorted`, which behaves roughly like this -- calculate a tuple from the object, and then compare the tuples.

Is there some feature of python, that allows defining a class-level function, from which all comparison function *and* a `__hash__` function are derived, similarly to what I do manually?

## Related question

There is [__key__ parameter for classes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158351/key-parameter-for-classes-in-python), but it considers only comparison operators. The `__hash__` function is never considered. As a result the question looks similar, but treats only a subset of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) module from Standard Library:

> This module provides a decorator and functions for automatically
> adding generated special methods such as `__init__()` and `__repr__()` to
> user-defined classes. It was originally described in PEP 557.

this include also options for [generating comparison and hash special methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass).

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(order=True)
class Foo:
    field1: int
    field2: int


spam = Foo(1, 2)
eggs = Foo(2, 3)
foo = Foo(2, 1)
bar = Foo(2, 1)

print(spam > eggs)
print(eggs == foo)
print(bar < eggs)
print(dir(Foo))
```

output

```
False
False
True
['__annotations__', '__class__', '__dataclass_fields__',
 '__dataclass_params__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__',
 '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__',
 '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', 
 '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```

We don't have full information about your class, so it's difficult to tell if it will solve your problem.

Comment: It *might* solve the problem. In the case at hand, I was using a class to represent a "calendar week" entry in a log, which originally was a `namedtuple("CalendarWeek", "year weak")`. Then I made it into a regular class, when I needed to add an annotation, that however shouldn't be taken into account for comparison and hashing. In this scenario, I would need to exclude some fields. In hindsight I should probably have kept `CalendarWeek` as a pure "tuple" class, and should have stored the annotations in a dict, or create a class containing the `CalendarWeek` plus annotation.

Comment: Assuming you have more than one log entry with same year and week, than it will be a problem to make `__eq__()` and  `__hash__()` based only on these 2 fields. If there is one entry per (year, week) then it doesn't matter if auto generated method will include the annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own class-decorator to automatically add `__hash__`, `__eq__` and `__lt__` in terms of a `__key__` (or other known method name).

```py
def key_hash(self):
    return hash(self.__key__())

def key_lt(self, other):
    return self.__key__() < other.__key__()

def key_eq(self, other):
    return self.__key__() == other.__key__()


def keyed(cls):
    for op_name, op_func in (("__hash__", key_hash), ("__lt__", key_lt), ("__eq__", key_eq)):
        setattr(cls, op_name, op_func)
    return cls
```

This can be applied just like `total_ordering` and also combined with it:

```py
@functools.total_ordering
@keyed
class X:
    def __init__(self, field1, field2):
        self.field1, self.field2 = field1, field2

    def __key__(self): return self.field1, self.field2
```

If you always want `keyed` and `functools.total_ordering`, they can be merged into one decorator as well.

```py
def total_keyed(cls):
    for op_name, op_func in (("__hash__", key_hash), ("__lt__", key_lt), ("__eq__", key_eq)):
        setattr(cls, op_name, op_func)
    return functools.total_ordering(cls)
```

Comment: So I take it, there is no builtin feature?

Comment: @kdb Not based on an arbitrary ``__key__``. The ``dataclasses`` mentioned by @buran are the closest thing offered by the standard library.